# Why is Ruby on Rails not saving my data?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job, rails-activerecord

This is a class I wrote to trace a background activity in my Rails application.

My problem is that the `status` field is updated correctly but the `logs` field is not. Any idea why?

ps1: i can see in the logs that `tmp_logs` contains the data I want, ie the list of html files found from a root directory)

ps2: this code is run via `rake` and the `delayed_job` gem.

```
class MaintenanceOperation < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :logs, :status, :operation

  def track_object_elements_in_html
    status = "started"
    tmp_logs = logs
    self.save
    begin
      nb_files = 0
      html_files = File.join(my_root, "**", "*.{html,htm,HTML,HTM}")
      Dir.glob(html_files).each do |file|
        nb_files += 1
        tmp_logs << file << "\n"
        logger.debug tmp_logs
      end
      tmp_logs << "Found #{nb_files} files." << "\n"
      self.logs = tmp_logs

      self.status = "done"
    rescue Exception => e
      logger.error "Finished performing maintenance operation with error"
      logger.error e.message
      e.backtrace.each { |line| logger.error line }
      logger.error "Flagging as error"
      self.status = "error"
    end
    self.save
  end
end
```

EDIT:

I can see empty transactions in my logs when saving after changing the `logs`.

```
2013-02-18 19:15:28.981 [meh]  (0.1ms)  begin transaction (pid:80725)
2013-02-18 19:15:28.982 [meh]  (0.0ms)  commit transaction (pid:80725)
```

Comment: Try `#save!`, it'll show errors. (They went against Ruby convention here that ! is an unsafe method, it raises errors on failure.)

Comment: I don't get errors and I can see the following empty transaction in the logs: 2013-02-18 19:15:28.981 [meh]  (0.1ms)  begin transaction (pid:80725)
2013-02-18 19:15:28.982 [meh]  (0.0ms)  commit transaction (pid:80725)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're being caught out by active record's change tracking here. In a nutshell, when you call save Active Record only updates the columns it thinks you have updated. In particular, if you modify an attribute in place (e.g. call gsub! or << on it) then Active Record doesn't spot that.

You are doing

```
self.logs = tmp_logs
```

however, `tmp_logs` was previously set to `logs`, so `self.logs` and `tmp_logs` are the same object. At the point at which you do the assignment, Active Record compares self.logs and tmp_logs, sees that they are the same object and so doesn't mark the column as changed.

You can either change your code so that Active Record thinks that you are assigning a fresh value to the logs column (for example set tmp_logs to self.logs.dup) or you can call `logs_will_change!` to tell Active Record that you have modified the attribute in place and that it should be updated the next time save is called.

Comment: tmp_logs = self.logs.dup worked perfectly and the explanation is clear. Thanks a lot!